# Regex match word if is it proceeded by another word

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a regular expression to match all instances of a word only if the first characters of the line are //.

So with the following example...

```
//foo bar
//bar foo
Something else with the word foo
```

The first two lines would be matches on the word foo. But the third line would not have a match because the // characters are not present before the word foo.

So far I've only managed to match the word regardless of if it is preceded by // using this...

```
\bfoo\b
```

OR to match the word if it immediately follows the // characters.

```
#*\/\/foo
```

Comment: You could try [`/^\/\/.*(foo)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/4PMUHT/1), the `foo` is captured in group 1

Comment: You can't match *just* the target word because look behinds can't be variable length. The closest you can get is Hao Wu's suggestion.

Comment: Are you replacing the string? In JavaScript? What is the expected final result?

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```js
    var data = `//foo bar
//bar foo
Something else with the word foo
//foo test more foo
//not has with defaul word - not match
    `;
    function getAllInstancesOfAWord(word) {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^\/\/(.*${word}.*)`, 'gm');
      console.log(regex);
      // Use regex match function
      const array = data.match(regex);
      // console.log(array);
      for (let i=0;i<array.length; i++){
        console.log(`Found instance word contain "${word}" begin with "//" = ${array[i].substring(2)}`);
      }
    }
    getAllInstancesOfAWord('foo');
    getAllInstancesOfAWord('not');
```

Note:

`^\/\/(.*foo.*)`: Get instance string contain the word “foo”, begin with “//”.

`string.substring(2)`: Get all chars start from index 2 to end, means to exclude “//”.

Tell me, if I’m wrong with your idea, more knowledge more power, right!